# Unable to mount partition / corrupt partition

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer but have 2 NTFS partitions as well which I access now and then. One of them (C) contains a Windows 7 install, the other partition (D) contains data. Recently I have used Gparted boot disc to resize the D partition but that failed (stating the resize action had failed) and this resulted in a corrupt partition. After that it was not possible to mount the partition any more from Ubuntu. Several linux tools suggested to run chkdsk from Windows. Also almost all forum posts I consulted suggested that.

The weird thing is that I am not able to get anything Windows-like running anymore:

- Windows 7 hangs at the "Starting Windows" screen and does not continue, also not if I let it run for several hours
- The Windows 7 rescue utility on the Windows 7 installation disc hangs on the screen where I select the hard disc to repair
- Installing Windows 7 on another (empty) partition hangs (during initialization, before the installation comments)
- Windows 7 mini (from Hiren's boot disc) hangs as well (only the wallpaper shows, then nothing)

Ran many rescue tools, both in Ubuntu and from boot CD's, nothing worked, all of them hang or suggest to run chkdsk /f. The only thing is that I have now managed to corrupt the C partition as well so Windows 7 does not boot anymore.

I have 2 questions:

- how is it possible that a corruption on partition D can affect the OS on partition C?
- how to fix this situation?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: After many days of trying nothing worked. I think the problem was that either there was a sector size problem or overlapping partitions but fixing that would endanger my Linux partitions. Undelete was possible but took about a month to finish (testdisk estimation). Decided to format both C and D.